Categorical waterfall chart not stacking correctly
Background I have this waterfall chart with two different categories: Extra ordinary and ordinary. I want to stack them together and create this "staircase/waterfall" movement. However, something is wrong in my function as the output is as follows:
So the first thing that is wrong, is that it gets the first stacked bar completely wrong. Next, there is no "staircase-movement" along the x-values.
A reproducible code is here:
waterfall_stacked <- function(data, x_title = "Coupon Rate Group", y_title = "Value", graph_title = "Coupon Redemption Data") {
  
  # Ensure the data is ordered correctly
  data <- data %>%
    arrange(KuponRenteGrouped, Category)
  
  # Calculate cumulative sums and start/end positions
  data <- data %>%
    group_by(KuponRenteGrouped) %>%
    mutate(
      CumulativeValue = cumsum(Value)
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(
      Start = lag(CumulativeValue, default = 0),
      End = CumulativeValue
    )
  
  # Set factor levels to control x-axis order
  levels_order <- c("[-0.5, 0 and 0.5%]", "[2.0 and 2.5%]", "[3.0 and 3.5%]", "1.00%", "1.50%", "4.00%", 
                    "5.00%", "6.00%", "Other", "Total")
  data$KuponRenteGrouped <- factor(data$KuponRenteGrouped, levels = levels_order)
  
  # Add IDs for plotting
  data$id <- as.numeric(factor(data$KuponRenteGrouped, levels = levels_order))
  
  # Adjust colors for the bars
  colors <- c("Ordinary" = "#c8f464", "Extra ordinary" = "#ff6969", "Ordinary Total" = "#55646e", "Extra ordinary Total" = "#6e5564")
  
  # Adjust the labels for total rows
  data <- data %>%
    mutate(Category = ifelse(KuponRenteGrouped == "Total" & Category == "Ordinary", "Ordinary Total",
                             ifelse(KuponRenteGrouped == "Total" & Category == "Extra ordinary", "Extra ordinary Total", Category)))
  
  # Generate breaks and labels for the x-axis
  breaks <- as.numeric(factor(levels_order, levels = levels_order))
  labels <- levels_order
  
  # Plot
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = id, fill = Category)) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = id - 0.4, xmax = id + 0.4, ymin = Start, ymax = End), color = "black", alpha = 0.95) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = id + 0.4, xend = id + 0.6, y = End, yend = End), color = "black") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = labels) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
    labs(title = graph_title, x = x_title, y = y_title) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "top",
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 12, face = "bold"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16, face = "bold"))
  
  return(p)
}




CouponRedemptionData_long <- structure(list(KuponRenteGrouped = c("[-0.5, 0 and 0.5%]", "[-0.5, 0 and 0.5%]", 
                                    "[2.0 and 2.5%]", "[2.0 and 2.5%]", "[3.0 and 3.5%]", "[3.0 and 3.5%]", 
                                    "1.00%", "1.00%", "1.50%", "1.50%", "4.00%", "4.00%", "5.00%", 
                                    "5.00%", "6.00%", "6.00%", "Other", "Other", "Total", "Total"
), Category = c("Ordinary", "Extra ordinary", "Ordinary", "Extra ordinary", 
                "Ordinary", "Extra ordinary", "Ordinary", "Extra ordinary", "Ordinary", 
                "Extra ordinary", "Ordinary", "Extra ordinary", "Ordinary", "Extra ordinary", 
                "Ordinary", "Extra ordinary", "Ordinary", "Extra ordinary", "Ordinary", 
                "Extra ordinary"), Value = c(-2486.07213523463, -1.63034770324489, 
                                             -909.558490247313, -5.05899091123594, -441.215118338973, -44.6833745314423, 
                                             -1864.32516031896, -6.66980344773318, -989.904080278175, -2.22086649188098, 
                                             -489.756623652007, -72.4061903560187, -774.611623995622, -2311.28579738599, 
                                             -56.5953120488995, -1960.36281564223, -10.7295231283663, -2.47831507741966, 
                                             -8022.76806724294, -4406.7965015472)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
                                             ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
waterfall_stacked(CouponRedemptionData_long)

I have previously made this function work with just a single category:
waterfall <- function(data, x_title = "X-axis Label", y_title = "Y-axis Label", graph_title = "Title", date_format = "%b %y") {
  desc_col <- names(data)[1]
  amount_col <- names(data)[2]
  
  data[[desc_col]] <- factor(data[[desc_col]], levels = data[[desc_col]])
  
  data$id <- seq_along(data[[amount_col]])
  
  data$type <- ifelse(data[[amount_col]] > 0, "increase", "decrease")
  data[nrow(data), "type"] <- "net"  # Set last as net
  
  data$end <- cumsum(data[[amount_col]])
  data$end <- c(head(data$end, -1), 0)
  data$start <- c(0, head(data$end, -1))
  
  data$type <- factor(data$type, levels = c("decrease", "increase", "net"))
  
  colors <- get_default_colors()  # Get colors from function
  
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = as.numeric(id), fill = type)) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, ymin = end, ymax = start)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = data$id, labels = data[[desc_col]]) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +  # Use comma for thousands separator
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("decrease" = colors[7],  # Red-pink for decrease
                                 "increase" = colors[3],  # Lime green for increase
                                 "net" = colors[1])) +    # Dark blue for net
    geom_text(aes(x = id, y = ifelse(type == "increase", end, start), label = scales::comma(data[[amount_col]]), vjust = ifelse(data[[amount_col]] > 0, -0.3, 1.3)), size = 3, fontface = "bold") +
    labs(title = graph_title, x = x_title, y = y_title) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "none", 
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 12, face = "bold"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16, face = "bold"))
  
  return(p)
}
CouponResultTotalRedemptions<- structure(list(KuponRenteGrouped = c("0.0", "1.00%", "1.50%", 
                                     "2.0", "3.0", "4.00%", "5.00%", "6.00%", "Other", "Total redemptions"
), TotalRedemptions = c(-2487.702491, -1870.994976, -992.124955, 
                        -914.617489, -485.89851, -562.16284, -3085.897447, -2017.09004, 
                        -13.337623, -12429.826371)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
 
RedemptionsWaterfall <- waterfall(CouponResultTotalRedemptions, "Coupon rates", "", "Redemptions over the latest notice period")


Which produced this graph:

Which has the staircase structure I need - but this function cannot handle the categories which I try to incorporate in the categorical waterfall chart. Any ideas to fix this?

Make sure you don't (re)arrange anything that gets mapped to your x-axis after you calculate the cumsums. Print your intermediate dataframe to the console (add magrittr's %T>% print() after the last mutate ) and check that Start and End are ordered correctly by id.
